# Pandas join merges x with x+1

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm trying to join two tables on an ID column (each ID has the form of "ABCxxx" with three numbers), slightly complicated by the fact that df1 has a clean column with the IDs but df2 contains the ID embedded in a long string and it can show up at any place within the string so it needs to be extracted from there. The problem is that this matches ID x with ID x+1, e.g. patient 113 from df1 with patient 114 from df2.
I assume the issue is that when I extract the ID from the lengthy string in df2, it is converted into an object, while the ID in df1 is an integer, which is why I transformed the ID column in df2 with df2['ID']=df2['ID'].astype(int), and something seems to go wrong there. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {
    'ID': ['001','002','003', '004','005'],
    'test': [10,20,30,40,50]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'ID': ['30942_ABC001_43424','45323_ABC001_45932','ABC002_94853_23948','ABC002_29304_90400','48958_34856_ABC003', '49384_ABCDE293_48593','28394_XYZ123_38485'],
    'score': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

df2 = df2[df2['ID'].str.contains('(ABC\d+\d+\d+)')]
df2['ID'] = df2['ID'].str.extract('(ABC\d+\d+\d+)', expand=True)

df2[['-','ID']] = df2['ID'].str.split('C',expand=True)
df1['ID']=df1['ID'].astype(int)
df2['ID']=df2['ID'].astype(int)
joined_table = df1.join(df2, on = 'ID', how = 'left', lsuffix = '_l')
```

EDIT: typo in code

Comment: The problem is that a `join` with `on` doesn't do what you might expect from SQL and other systems. It matches the left table's __column__ as named in `on` with the right table's __index__ - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html. To match the same-named column across both tables, it's `.merge` rather than `.join`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did it! I could have sworn I remembered join to work like that but apparently not